# SystemC Transfer Level Model Sockets: Two Way Communication

Tags: c++, sockets, systemc

In Doulos's SystemC Transfer Level Model documentation, it is written

> The top-level module of the hierarchy instantiates one initiator and
> one memory, and binds the initiator socket on the initiator to the
> target socket on the target memory. The sockets encapsulate everything
> you need for two-way communication between modules, including ports
> and exports for both directions of communication. One initiator socket
> is always bound to one target socket.

My understanding of this was that when you create an initiator and a target the initiator starts the communication by calling b_transport, thereby triggering the target, which can reply back. However, I have been writing some code and this does not seem to be the case. Let us look at an example.

I have a very basic implementation of an adder that can be talked to using transfer level modeling. This modules servers as the target.

adder.cc

```
#define SC_INCLUDE_DYNAMIC_PROCESS

#include "tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h"
#include "tlm_utils/simple_target_socket.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace std;

#include "adder.h"

adder::adder(sc_module_name name)
    : sc_module(name), socket("socket2")
{
    socket.register_b_transport(this, &adder::b_transport);
    socket.register_transport_dbg(this, &adder::transport_dbg);
}

void adder::b_transport(tlm::tlm_generic_payload& trans, sc_time& delay)
{
    tlm::tlm_command cmd = trans.get_command();
    sc_dt::uint64   addr = trans.get_address();
    uint32_t    *ptr = (uint32_t*)trans.get_data_ptr();
    unsigned int    len = trans.get_data_length();
    unsigned char   *byt = trans.get_byte_enable_ptr();
    unsigned int    wid = trans.get_streaming_width();

    addend1 = *ptr;
    addend2 = *(++ptr);
    add();
    cout << "addend1: " << addend1 << endl;
        cout << "addend2: " << addend2 << endl;     
    cout << "sum: " << sum << endl;

    uint32_t *return_sum_loc = ptr;

    for(int i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
        return_sum_loc++;
    }

    memcpy(return_sum_loc, (char*) &sum, sizeof(uint32_t));
    cout << "New sum for return: " << *(return_sum_loc) << endl;
}

unsigned int adder::transport_dbg(tlm::tlm_generic_payload& trans)
{
    return 0;
}

void adder::add()
{
    sum = addend1 + addend2;
}
```

Then I have a test_bench module that is going to serve as the initiator

test_bench.cc

```
#define SC_INCLUDE_DYNAMIC_PROCESS

#include "tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h"
#include "tlm_utils/simple_target_socket.h"

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace std;

#include "test_bench.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

test_bench::test_bench(sc_module_name name):
    sc_module(name), socket("socket")
{
    SC_THREAD(run_tests);
}

void test_bench::run_tests()
{
    ifstream infile("./adder.golden.dat");
    ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("./adder.dat");
    
    uint32_t theoretical_sum = 0;

    while(infile >> data[0] >> data[1] >> theoretical_sum)
    {   
        tlm::tlm_generic_payload *trans = new tlm::tlm_generic_payload;
        sc_time delay = sc_time(10, SC_NS);
    
        cout << "Sending" << endl;
        cout << "Data[0]: " << data[0] << endl;
        cout << "Data[1]: " << data[1] << endl; 

        trans->set_data_ptr((unsigned char*)data);

        socket->b_transport(*trans, delay);

        cout << "data[2]" << data[2] << endl;

        ofs << data[0] << "\t" << data[1] << "\t" << data[2] << "\n";       

        delete trans;
    }
    infile.close();
    ofs.close();

    printf ("Comparing against output data \n");
    if (system("diff -w adder.dat adder.golden.dat")) 
    {

        cout << "*******************************************" << endl;
        cout << "FAIL: Output DOES NOT match the golden output" << endl;
        cout << "*******************************************" << endl;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << "*******************************************" << endl;
        cout << "PASS: The output matches the golden output!" << endl;
        cout << "*******************************************" << endl;
    }

}
```

Here is the parent module that instantiates and connects them.

main.cc

```
#include "systemc.h"
#include "tlm_utils/simple_initiator_socket.h"
#include "tlm_utils/simple_target_socket.h"
#include "tlm_utils/tlm_quantumkeeper.h"

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace sc_dt;
using namespace std;

#include "test_bench.h"
#include "adder.h"

SC_MODULE(Top)
{
    test_bench  *tb;
    adder       *ad;

    sc_signal<bool> rst;

    sc_signal<bool> tb_irq;
    sc_signal<bool> ad_irq;

    Top(sc_module_name name) :
        rst("rst")
    {
        tb = new test_bench("test_bench");
        ad = new adder("adder");

        tb->socket.bind(ad->socket);
        tb->irq(tb_irq);
        ad->irq(ad_irq);
    }

};

int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Top *top = new Top("Top");
    sc_start();

    
}
```

When I run the executable this is the output I get.

> < 1     0       0
>
> < 1     1       0
>
> < 2     1       0
>
> < 2     2       0
>
> < 2     3       0
>
> < 3     3       0
>
> < 4     3       0
>
> < 4     4       0
>
> < 5     4       0
>
> < 5     5       0

---

> 1     0       1
>
> 1     1       2
>
> 2     1       3
>
> 2     2       4
>
> 2     3       5
>
> 3     3       6
>
> 4     3       7
>
> 4     4       8
>
> 5     4       9
>
> 5     5       10

---

FAIL: Output DOES NOT match the golden output

So my original thought was that you were passing by value this payload into the b_transport function of an initiator that is bound to a target. The target will receive and decode this payload. This part is happening. I am able to parse the uint32_t s passed in by value to the data[]. **What I eventually realized based on my 0 return values, that were written into the memory that was passed, is that this is not actually passed by value.** For some reason it is created as a pointer type, then it is dereferenced when passed. **This in essence destroys that target's ability to manipulate the memory that was passed to hand back a response to the initiator.**

So this whole two-way communication thing Aynsley mentioned has me a little confused. By two-way does, he mean both modules need target and initiator sockets to enable two-way communication?

Comment: adder.h is missing

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature of b_transport call:

```
void b_transport( tlm::tlm_generic_payload& trans, sc_time& delay )
```

Payload is passed by reference, so target can modify it. Initiator can read returned value from the same payload object.

> So this whole two-way communication thing Aynsley mentioned has me a
>   little confused. By two-way does, he mean both modules need target and
>   initiator sockets to enable two-way communication?

Blocking transport protocol implemented by b_transport call is unidirectional. Initiator module is active, target module is passive. Transaction finishes in a single call. Target is allowed to call wait() inside b_transport implementation.

But TLM2.0 also supports non-blocking protocol that consists of two calls:

- nb_transport_fw from initiator to target
- nb_transport_bw from target to initiator

This bidirectional protocol allows more fine-grained modeling of bus timing. For example you can model of out-of-order transaction processing in AMBA AXI bus.

In practice however almost everyone uses b_transport. Most models I've seen don't even support non-blocking interface.

Comment: I find the approximately timed style so cumbersome (since it forces a style of using callbacks rather than a straightforward programming style using SC_THREADS).  In your experience, does anyone use the nb_transport interface and if not, how do you accurately model resource contention with b_transport if you want to do performance estimation?

Comment: @sheridp In my experience nb_transport is not used in practice. Most SystemC models are loosely timed, used for early software development.